# Pass multiline string to macro

Tags: iphone, ios7

I am using macro in constants. Here is my code.

```
#define kTermsConditions(message) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"USER TERMS AND CONDITIONS

PLEASE READ THIS BEFORE ACCESSING THE INC. (“”) ONLINE  SERVICE.  BY ACCESSING THE U, YOU AGREE TO BE BOUND BY THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS BELOW.  IF YOU DO NOT WISH TO BE BOUND BY THESE TERMS AND CONDITIONS, YOU MAY NOT USE THE SITE.

1. ALL PERSONS USING THIS SITE AGREE TO REPORT ON (MANIFESTS) IN ACCORDANCE WITH 49 U.S.C, AND 8 C.F.R. PARTS 217, 231, AND 251.

2. USERS MUST BE AFFILIATED WITH AN APPROVED OPERATOR.  AN CHOOSING TO USE THE SERVICES OF SUCH USER, WHETHER AN AIRCRAFT OPERATOR EMPLOYEE OR A THIRD-PARTY, IS SPECIFICALLY AWARE THAT IT IS LIABLE FOR ALL ACTIONS OR INACTION OF THE USER WHILE TRANSMITTING ON ITS BEHALF.  RELIANCE ON A REGISTERED USER IS NOT A DEFENSE FOR INCORRECT OR INCOMPLETE DATA, OR FOR PENALTY ACTIONS AGAINST THE.

3. ELIGIBILITY FOR USE OF AND ACCESS TO THIS SITE IS SUBJECT TO FINAL APPROVAL AND ACCEPTANCE BY.
```

But i am not bale this lengthy multiline string to macro. Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a new line code character( if it is called that way), which just a `\`. This will tell the compiler that the string will continue on the next line.

```
#define kTermsConditions(message) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"USER TERMS AND CONDITIONS\
\
PLEASE READ THIS BEFORE ACCESSING THE INC. (“”) ONLINE  SERVICE.  BY ACCESSING THE U, YOU AGREE TO BE BOUND BY THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS BELOW.  IF YOU DO NOT WISH TO BE BOUND BY THESE TERMS AND CONDITIONS, YOU MAY NOT USE THE SITE.\
\n\n\
1. ALL PERSONS USING THIS MCL/APIS SITE AGREE TO REPORT ON (MANIFESTS) IN ACCORDANCE WITH 49 U.S.C, AND 8 C.F.R. PARTS 217, 231, AND 251.\
\n\n\
2. USERS MUST BE AFFILIATED WITH AN APPROVED OPERATOR.  AN CHOOSING TO USE THE SERVICES OF SUCH USER, WHETHER AN AIRCRAFT OPERATOR EMPLOYEE OR A THIRD-PARTY, IS SPECIFICALLY AWARE THAT IT IS LIABLE FOR ALL ACTIONS OR INACTION OF THE USER WHILE TRANSMITTING ON ITS BEHALF.  RELIANCE ON A REGISTERED MCL/APIS USER IS NOT A DEFENSE FOR INCORRECT OR INCOMPLETE DATA, OR FOR PENALTY ACTIONS AGAINST THE.\
\n\n\
3. ELIGIBILITY FOR USE OF AND ACCESS TO THIS SITE IS SUBJECT TO FINAL APPROVAL AND ACCEPTANCE BY."]
```

Answer (score 0):

Three things you need to know:

How to create long strings without having an impossible long line: That's very easy. If you write multiple string literals one after the other, the compiler turns them into one. For example

```
@"This "
"is "
"a "
"very "
"long "
"string."
```

is exactly the same as

```
@"This is a very long strong."
```

How to create strings containing line breaks (do that only if you have to, for example for text that you want to come up in multiple paragraphs): Just insert \n into your string.

How to make very long macros: If the last character in a line is a backslash character with nothing following it (not even a space character) then the compiler concatenates that line with the next line. You use that to create long macros. Like

```
#define MYSTRING @"This "\
    "is "\
    "a "\
    "very "\
    "long "\
    "macro. "
```